# Outputting a unique string when a user from a list is not a key in the Dictionary

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to change this line "if name not in possible_respondents" to "if the name that is located in possible_respondents isn't inside favorite_languages, output this string."

```
favorite_languages = {
    'jen': 'python',
    'sarah': 'c',
    'edward': 'ruby',
    'phil': 'python',
    }

possible_respondents = ['edward','tracy','crab', 'jen']

for name in favorite_languages.keys():
    if name not in possible_respondents:
        print(f"Please take the poll, {name.title()}!")
    else:
        print(f"Thank you for responding, {name.title()}!")
```

The code works but not the way I want it to.

**Output:**

```
Thank you for responding, Jen!
Please take the poll, Sarah!
Thank you for responding, Edward!
Please take the poll, Phil!
```

**The output I want for example is:**

```
Thank you for responding, Jen!
Please take the poll, Tracy!
Thank you for responding, Edward!
Please take the poll, Crab!
Thank you for responding, Phil!
```

Comment: how do you want it to be then ?

Comment: "if the name that is located in possible_respondents isn't inside favorite_languages" = "if the name is located in possible_respondents and isn't inside favorite_languages" = `if name in possible_respondents and name not in favorite_languages`.

Comment: @Datanovice two entries inside possible_respondents aren't in the original dictionary; i want to be able to output to the screen that those users should take the poll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this, I would create a list of total names to iterate over by combining the keys and the list whilst removing duplicates.

```
total_names = set(list(favorite_languages.keys()) + possible_respondents)
```

then iterate as you've done :

```
for name in total_names:
    if name not in favorite_languages.keys():
        print(f"Please take the poll, {name.title()}!")
    else:
        print(f"Thank you for responding, {name.title()}!")


Thank you for responding, Phil!
Thank you for responding, Sarah!
Thank you for responding, Jen!
Please take the poll, Tracy!
Please take the poll, Crab!
Thank you for responding, Edward!
```

Comment: thank you, i don't know why i didn't think about it like that

Comment: @S.Coughing do you want the result to include Sarah as well ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you're trying to ask, let me know if this answers it.

You're iterating through the keys in favorite_languages right now, but it seems that you want to be checking through the possible_respondants and seeing if they exist as keys in favorite languages. If so, you would iterate through possible_respondants and see if they are in favorite languages, essentially the reverse of what you have now, so:

```
for name in possible_respondants:
    if name not in favorite_languages:
        print(f"Please take the poll, {name.title()}!")
    else:
        print(f"Thank you for responding, {name.title()}!")
```

You could also use:

```
if name not in favorite_languages.keys()
```

Or:

```
if not favorite_languages.has_key(name):
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it works, but the code leaves out Sarah and Phil, and "possible_respondants" should be "possible_respondents": this is if i do "if name not in favorite_languages.keys()"

Answer (score 0):

Although the question seems unclear, from reading the comments it sounds like you need to then loop through the `possible_respondents` list and compare it to the `favourite_languages.keys()` list:

```
 for name in possible_respondents:
    if name not in favorite_languages.keys():
        print(f"Please take the poll, {name.title()}!")
```